# How to divide each cell of a row with Maximum value of the same row

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheet with multiple rows and columns. All having some floating point numbers.

I am trying to get the maximum value of all cells within each row and divide all cells in that row with the max value in that row. can we write a formula to achieve this? Any pointers on this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:F9<>"", A1:F9/QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:F9),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( ,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A9), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(A1:A9)-ROW(A1)+1&"),", ""))), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be a bit simplistic, but here it is.
You can try to drag the formula below. The if statement is for a situation when zero is your maximum value in line and you could not divide with zero.

```
=IF(max($A1:$D1)<>0;A1/max($A1:$D1);"Sorry max value is zero")
```